# Xcode 4 / Interface Builder "master" view UITabBarController template

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I started an iPhone App with the Xcode template for UITabBarController, which created a couple of default UIViews (MainWindow, FirstView and SecondView).

The MainWindow xib shows the tabbar itself, which can be configured there.

FirstView and SecondView have an unselectable UITabBar anchored to the bottom, which is ostensibly to show the relationship to MainWindow.

Note that I've created many new views that are part of the main UITabBar and they work fine, but they don't show that UITabBar at the bottom in Interface Builder.

My question is, how does that work, and how can I create a new view such that it will show that unselectable UITabBar at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is simply Interface Builder's "simulated metrics" and it shouldn't actually have any bearing on the app's behavior. But this is how you can change it:[image]